# Recurrent sequence convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove this but I can't, I tried to use an infinite integral for it but I can't do it.
Let $$f_o(x)$$ continuos in $$0\leq x\leq a$$ Show that the sequence of functions defined by $$f_n(x)-\int_{0}^{x}{x}f_{n-1}(t)dt$$ for $$n=1,2,3,\ldots$$ converges uniformly to $$f(x)≡0$$ in $[0,a]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being continuous, $f_0$ is bounded on $[0,a]$. Suppose $|f_0(x)| \leq M$. Let us show by induction that $|f_n(x) | \leq M\frac {x^{2n}} {b_n}$ where $b_0=1$ and $b_{n+1}=(2n+1)b_n$ . This is true for $n=0$. Suppose it is true for $n$. Then $|f_{n+1}(x)| \leq  x \int_0^{x} Mt^{2n}/b_n=\frac {Mx^{2n+2}} {b_{n+1}}$. We have proved out claim. Now use the convegence of the series $\sum \frac {a^{n}} {b_n}$ to conclude that $\frac {a^{n}} {n!} \to 0$. [Use ratio test for convergence of the series; $\frac {b_{n+1}} {b_n} =\frac  1 {2n+1}$].